# does similarity based hash exist?

Tags: algorithm

For a given string, and its slight mutation, usual hashes are unpredictably different. Is there some algorithm that maintains some amount of prefix when changes are minor?

```
hash("That is all they want to teach you") -> da9dad9039d33d3dkdkd
hash("And that is all they want to make you!") -> da9dad9039d3gs09fsd0
```

Is there some algorithm that lends to comparison, returning a value from 0 to 1?

```
compare(hash(s1), hash(s2)) -> 0.7
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a hashing function, or just an algorithm in general?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

taken from this question:

[String similarity score/hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323977/string-similarity-score-hash)

which is almost a duplicate..